# How to use responses in neuralintents python library

Tags: python, json, module

I created a voice assistant using python **neuralintents** module. but it didn't give a way to use **responses** in **intents.json** to give a feedback for user. Instead it is mapping response to a function.

Is there any way to use responses in intents.json.

I got this by watching this tutorial :
https://youtu.be/SXsyLdKkKX0

Github repo :
https://github.com/NeuralNine/neuralintents

***Source code from video***

```
from email.mime import audio
from fileinput import filename
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts
import sys

import webbrowser

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

speaker = tts.init()
speaker.setProperty('rate', 150)

todo_list = ['Go shopping', 'Clean Room', 'Recpard Videos']


def create_note():
    global recognizer
    speaker.say("What do you want to write into your note")
    speaker.runAndWait()

    done = False

    while not done:
        try:
            with speech_recognition.Microphone as mic:
                recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
                audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

                note = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                note = note.lower()

                speaker.say("Choose a filename!")
                speaker.runAndWait()

                recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
                audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

                filename = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                filename = filename.lower()

            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(note)
                done = True
                speaker.say(f"I sucessfully created the note {filename}")
                speaker.runAndWait
        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
            speaker.say("I did not understand you! Please try again!")
            speaker.runAndWait()


def add_todo():
    global recognizer

    speaker.say("What doto do you want to add?")
    speaker.runAndWait()

    done = False

    while not done:
        try:
            with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
                recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
                audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

                item = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                item = item.lower()

                todo_list.append(item)
                done = True

                speaker.say(f"I added {item} to the to do list!")
                speaker.runAndWait()

        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
            speaker.say("I did not understand. Please try again!")
            speaker.runAndWait()


def show_todos():
    speaker.say("The items in your to do list are following")
    for item in todo_list:
        speaker.say(item)
    speaker.runAndWait()


def hello():
    speaker.say("Hello. What can I do for you?")
    speaker.runAndWait()


def exitt():
    speaker.say("Bye")
    speaker.runAndWait()
    sys.exit(0)


mapppings = {
    "greeting": hello,
    "create_note": create_note,
    "add_todos": add_todo,
    "show_todos": show_todos,
    "goodbye": exitt,
}

assistant = GenericAssistant('intents.json', intent_methods=mapppings)
assistant.train_model()
assistant.save_model()



def talk(text):
    engine = tts.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
    engine. setProperty("rate", 150)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


while True:
    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

            command = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            command = command.lower()
        assistant.request(command)

    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the assistant to speak the response you call the function talk and pass `assistant.request(command)` as a parameter, but if you have bindings for adding todo etc. You first call the `assistant.request(command)` alone and after that, you check if the request has any response, and if it does you pass the response to the talk function

```py
def talk(text):
    engine = tts.init()
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
    engine. setProperty("rate", 150)
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

while True:
    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)

            command = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            command = command.lower()
        assistant.request(command)
        if(assistant.request(command))
            talk(assistant.request(command))

    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
```